# The Adobe Flash plugin has crashed

Tags: firefox, flash, crash

I installed ubuntu a few days ago. I remember that Flash Player works immediately after instaling system. Now I was disappointed because I can't load a website that use this technology. What can I do to fix it? I use default internet browser - Firefox and Ubuntu 16.04.

I have this statement on the any website with Flash:
*"The Adobe Flash plugin has crashed. Please reload the page to try again."*

Comment: Follow this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/adobe-flash-plugin-has-crashed

Comment: @Redbob Official adobe flash website says that I have the latest Flash version. (Website: http://get.adobe.com/pl/flashplayer/about/) It says: _"You have version 26.0.0.151 installed"_ and the latest version for every browsers is 26.0.0.151.

Answer (score 1):

Flash plugin is not installed during system installation.  You have three options:

1. Install `flashplugin-installer` by typing `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` in a terminal window. This will install the flash plugin for **Firefox**.
2. Install **google chrome** by downloading the package from google.  Chrome is using pepper-flash which is embedded in it and will be installed with Chrome.
3. Install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` by typing `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` in a terminal window. This package will install flash and a complete multimedia audio and video codec support.

Comment: `flashplugin-installer` is installed at system installation is you choose to install some third party software.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I tried all these commands but it wasn't helpful. I have installed third party software. Anyway official adobe flash website says that I have the latest Flash version. (Website: http://get.adobe.com/pl/flashplayer/about/) It says: _"You have version 26.0.0.151 installed"_ and the latest version for every browsers is 26.0.0.151.

Comment: wasn't helpful neither : still crashing